# Cannot open source file "opencv2/face.hpp"

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I have OpenCV 3.0.0 configured on Visual Studio 2013. 
It gives the error :

```
 'Cannot open source file "opencv2/face.hpp'
```

Does it not come with pre-built library in opencv 3.0.0?
So how shall I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face Recognition is an extra module and not included as standard with OpenCV.

The repo for all the extra modules can be found here:
https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib

You can rebuild OpenCV and include it along with any other extra modules you need, instructions are given in the readme.